# Does the Earth's core have the same rotation period as its surface?

Tags: geology, core

Does the Earth's core have the same rotation period as the surface?

Comment: While very close to the same, the inner core, outer core, and mantle do not at exactly the same rates. The outer core currently rotates slightly slower than does the mantle and crust, while the inner core currently rotates slightly faster than does the mantle and crust.